# Create atlas series with yearly maps from 1920 to 2018

Tags: qgis, atlas

I have a lot of maps I need to create. One for each year that shows what have happened in the map area. First map are supposed to shot 1920. Then the next one are supposed to shot 1920+1921. And the next after that are supposed to show 1920+1921+1922.

I'm wondering if it's possible to create an atlas that can do this ?

I have to create one each year until 2018.

Comment: I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor. For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Answer (score 2):

If you configure your atlas with a coverage layer which contains one feature per year from 1920 to 2018, and if you affect the atlas pagename to the year's field (integer), you can style another layer which contains datas with an integer field for the year :

- Layer properties > Symbology > Rules : `"my_layer_year_field" <= to_int(@atlas_pagename)`

In the case where the coverage layer field is not the year's field, you can use the following expression : `"my_layer_year_field" <= to_int(attribute(@atlas_feature, 'my_layer_year_field'))`.

If you pre-vizualize your atlas, the symbology will filter automatically data in function of the year.